# Is it possible to have multiple masks with clip-path?

Tags: css, mask, clip-path

Hi,

I wonder whether it's possible to use more than one mask on the same element, just like this:

```
clip-path:polygon(8% 0%, 8% 7%, 14% 12%), polygon(96.4%, 92% 96.4%, 97% 92.3%), polygon(97% 15%, 99% 13%, 99% 0%);
```

With this I would be able to show only certain areas of the element that are separated from each other.

Thank you.

Comment: nop, just go read the spec on w3c or look at tutorials ;)

Comment: Any way around or?

Comment: Myabe stacking a few div and give each one mask ? or blend masks into a single one ?

Comment: But how to blend them if they are separated shapes?

Comment: like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbjjRd help your sel f with a generator like : http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator , you only need to had manually the coordonates in between the shapes

Comment: I see. There is a bridge between the 2 but so narrow its invisible, right?

Comment: Thanks. I guess thats the only way around.

Answer (score 40):

This is possible if you use clip-path with an SVG-defined `<clipPath>`

```css
.clip-svg {
  clip-path: url(#myClip);
}
```

```html
<img class="clip-svg" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/600/400">

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <polygon points="400,50 400,320, 140,300"/>
      <polygon points="450,10 500,200 600,100" />
      <polygon points="150,10 100,200 300,100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Confirmed working in Chrome 60, Firefox 55, Edge 85. Unfortunately doesn't work in IE.

Full browser support information [here](https://caniuse.com/css-clip-path).

Comment: I just tested your code snippet in both Edge and IE11, and it worked. Am I missing something about support? Also, MDN says, "Any number of the following elements, in any order..." which would seem to indicate your solution is appropriate usage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath#Usage_notes

Comment: Looks like it does work in recent versions of Edge, just didn't 3 years ago! I have tested in IE11 and it just shows the whole image. AFAIK IE11 doesn't support using the clip-path on HTML elements in this way.

Comment: @Zac, can you check what wrong with my code? Its only work with one polygon item, but does not with multile.

Comment: @Zac
`<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ7xG.jpg" style="clip-path: url(#myClip);">

<svg width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip"  clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0 0, 0 1, .54 .99, .5682 .156, .746 .151, .7397 .557, .51 .508, .54 .99, 1 1, 1 0" />
      <polygon points="0 0, 0 1, .737 1, .747 .321, .816 .321, .81 .666, .74 .645, .74 1, 1 1, 1 0" />
      /*  It doesn't work, but if delete one of them so its work with only one polygon */
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>`

Comment: @Zac, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73996512/svg-clipppath-multiple-polygon-elements-does-not-work

Answer (score 5):

You can also use CSS to make one polygon which goes in and out of element bounds  . See:

https://24ways.org/2018/clip-paths-know-no-bounds/

https://codepen.io/danwilson/pen/zMgrgb

```css
div {
  width: 80vmin;
  height: 80vmin;
  background: hsl(181, 90%, 52%);
  
  clip-path: polygon(30px 20px, 40px 200px, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 30%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple mask. But you can't use multiple clip-path. You can use multiple masks with clip-path.
you can use mask property with clip-path to make multiple masks.
like this example.

```css
#parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items :center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, black 50%, yellow 50%);
 }
 .multiple_mask{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%, 50% 50%);
    -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(45deg, black 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(180deg, black, transparent);
    mask-image: linear-gradient(45deg, black 50%, transparent 70%);
 }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="multiple_mask"></div>
  </div>
```

Hope you understand

Answer (score 2):

To use clip path for multiple clips you need to think of it like an etch-a-sketch. You have to complete the object and follow that line to the next object. Then come back to the previous object before moving to the next one.

```css
img {
        clip-path: polygon(14% 12%, 8% 0%, 8% 7%, 14% 12%, 87% 96.4%, 92% 96.4%, 97% 92.3%, 87% 96.4%, 14% 12%, 97% 15%, 99% 13%, 99% 0, 97% 15%, 14% 12% );
    }
```

```html
<img class="clip-svg" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/600/400"/>
```